# Relatively accessible introduction to Milnor-Witt $K$-theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology

I'm looking for a recommendable self-contained source to learn Milnor-Witt $K$-theory. Almost all papers that I found were research papers assuming reader's advanced knowledge on this topic. Does anybody know a script addressed to beginners on this topic? I have an algebro-topological background and I am familiar with (co)homologies and schemes at student/basic level.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I hope I'm wrong, but I do not think there is a gentle textbook covering this topic yet. It is very much anchored in the theory of motivic homotopy, and I would not expect any book not on motivic homotopy to spend any time on it. Maybe the most elementary text would be "An introduction to $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy theory" by Morel?

Comment: Morel's "$\mathbb{A}^1$-algebraic topology over a field" contains a section (2.1 Milnor-Witt K-theory of fields) that seems pretty independent to me. As far as I know there is no source solely focusing on it. In practice, a lot of the things you can say about it follow from knowledge about the Witt-group and Milnor K-theory. This is due to the fact that there is a pullback square relating these objects. A good source for the Witt theory part is Lam's "Introduction to quadratic forms over fields". Facts about Milnor K-theory can be found for example in the K-book and Milnor's original paper.